# Unable to process kafka-consumer messages in async thread in python 2.7 using trollius

Tags: python-2.7, apache-kafka, python-asyncio, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am new to Kafka so if I am missing out on something, please let me know? Use-case is as follow, there are three Kafka consumers running, and the messages read from these are processed and sent via post call to the client API, but the time taken by the client(for testing I have used 8 minutes) is not fixed so it can be greater than max.poll.timeout(for this case I have used 6 minutes) as well. For this, I was trying to pause() the consumer while the client sends back the response and then calling the resume() to get the next message from the kafka-broker using poll(). I tried with the below code to do processing in the async thread, but this is not getting executed asynchronously, and rebalancing is occurring and then all consumers are leaving the group. How can I handle this use case and why is the code not getting executed asynchronously?

versions:

- python 2.7
- kafka-python 1.4.6
- trollius 2.2.post1

```
import trollius as asyncio
from trollius import From

for message in consumer:
    consumer.pause(*consumer.assignment())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(thread_message_processor(consumer)),
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
    .....


@asyncio.coroutine
def thread_message_processor(consumer):
    # for testing I am using sleep as time taken by client API for processing
    yield From(asyncio.sleep(480))
    consumer.resume(*consumer.assignment())
```

Comment: I believe trollius is long abandoned and you should not attempt to use it. Use asyncio instead.

Comment: Problem is that its a legacy project and I need to fix this in python 2.7 only (which doesn't support asyncio). The closest thing I got was trollius.

Comment: In your place I'd try to solve it using synchronous code and threads and, if needed, post a StackOverflow question about _that_. Just forget about trollius.